# How to replace gulp insert.wrap with webpack equivalent

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I must replace gulp with webpack, but I have come across a problem. My gulp stream had following step:

```
.pipe( insert.wrap( '(function($){', '})(window.$);' ) );
```

I have to append the very same thing in webpack. Any plugins for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrapper-webpack-plugin`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrapper-webpack-plugin